# Entity FrameWork , many to many realtion , reading data from navigation properties of Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on asp.net web forms (C#) , with mysql and entity framework. 
There in my database , a User table is with many to many relationship with permission table , and a third table UserPermission to establish this relation. 
Following are the classes generated by entity framework data model.

```
 public class User{
 public int Serial { get; set; }
 public string User_Name { get; set;
 public virtual ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermission { get; set; }
 }
 public class Permission{
 public int Serial { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set;
 public virtual ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermission { get; set; }
 }
 public partial class UserPermission
 {
    public int Serial { get; set; }
    public int USER_Sr { get; set; }
    public int Permission_Sr { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Now my problem is , that based on a user id , i want read the permissions it's associated with. 
I want to have users with their assigned permissions , populate these into a gridview , where each row shows the record of a user , and there a combobox in that row contains the permissions , that user has gain.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To get permissions assigned to a user

```
var userPermissions = MyContext.Users.Find(userId).Permissions();
```

Where MyContext is your DbContext and Users is defined as DbSet in this context. You didn't specify what you are using to display information, so I can't help you on that.

Comment: Hello, I am using DbContext and yes Users is defined as DbSet in this context. I actually want to load all of the users , with all of their permissions inside an object , so that i can pass this object as a data source to a gridview , (aspx gridview) . and there inside the gridview i want these permissions to be shown inside a checkCombobox , e.g every row inside the grid , shows information about a single user , and a checkCombobox column displays the permission assigned to that user.

Comment: var userPermissions = MyContext.Users.Find(userId).Permissions(); is not working , 
The parameter passed to the find function is a string i guess , and then
MyContext.Users.Find(userId) , returns a User Object , and User.Permissions(); is nothing .

Comment: The `Find()` method expects the primary key of the entity. In your case that's probably `Serial` ? You should be able to pass  `MyContext.Users.ToList()` to your gridview and then iterate over the users and their respective permissions.

Comment: i think you intend to write MyContext.Users.Find(userId).UserPermissions();

Comment: can you please help me know if i am doing this with entity data source as data source of my gridview e.g <asp:EntityDataSource " id=a EntitySetName="users> 
and  <dx:ASPxGridView DataSourceID="a">
how can i iterate over the users and display the assigned permissions inside checkCombobox

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with ASP.NET controls. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949166/entitydatasource-accessing-a-collection-from-another-entity-in-gridview) and [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668221%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may be helpful.